# Learning how to use QGIS Expressions

Tags: qgis, expression, references

What is the best way to learn about expressions in QGIS?

Do you have any book recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure there is a book. Looking at the expression reference documentation is the best way to tackle all available expressions https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html

You may also look at video "Advanced QGIS Expressions" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXPCec8vgLA (related to https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/advanced-qgis.html#summary-aggregate-expressions)

Comment: Nyall Dawson also has a video that includes QGIS expressions at: https://youtu.be/h-mpUkwDdOQ